# MySQL distinct+sort query performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance

#### Problem

The following query takes in excess of 30 seconds to run unless:

- I remove the sort (query then <1 sec)
- I remove the distinct keyword: (query then <1 sec)
- Start removing joins (query then <5 secs)

#### Question

How can I make this query run in under 1 sec. Required: How can I get a unique list of meetings with the related data as described by the joins below including a sort of some kind.

The related data is used to both determining if there is a related field and also for doing GROUP_CONCAT operations - hence the requirement to have 3 different joins to the same bookeditems table.

Thanks in advance for any help & or suggestions! I've been banging my head on this one for a few hours!

#### Query

```
SELECT

DISTINCT( `meetings`.`id` ) AS `meeting_id`,
`meetings`.`uid` AS meeting_uid,
`meetings_SERV`.`id` AS meetings_SERV_id, 
`meetings_TRANSP`.`id` AS meetings_TRANSP_id, 
`meetings_ACCO`.`id` AS meetings_ACCO_id, 
`meetings_BOOKEDITEMS`.`id` AS meetings_BOOKEDITEMS_id

FROM `meetings` AS meetings 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `bookeditems` AS `meetings_SERV` 
ON `meetings`.`uid` = `meetings_SERV`.`meeting_uid`
AND 'SER' = `meetings_SERV`.`item_type` 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `bookeditems` AS `meetings_TRANSP` 
ON `meetings`.`uid` = `meetings_TRANSP`.`meeting_uid`
AND 'TRA' = `meetings_TRANSP`.`item_type` 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `bookeditems` AS `meetings_ACCO` 
ON `meetings`.`uid` = `meetings_ACCO`.`meeting_uid`
AND 'ACC' = `meetings_ACCO`.`item_type` 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `bookeditems` AS `meetings_BOOKEDITEMS` 
ON `meetings`.`uid` = `meetings_BOOKEDITEMS`.`meeting_uid` 

ORDER BY `meetings`.`datetime`

LIMIT 0, 50
```

#### Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookeditems` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meeting_uid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `meeting_uid` (`meeting_uid`(255)),
  KEY `index1` (`meeting_uid`(255),`item_type`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5889 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meetings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`(255)),
  KEY `datetime` (`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7487 ;
```

#### Result of EXPLAIN SELECT

```
id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys      | key         | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | meetings             | ALL  | NULL               | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                     | 7483 | Using temporary; Using filesort
1  | SIMPLE      | meetings_SERV        | ref  | meeting_uid,index1 | meeting_uid | 767     | test.meetings.uid        | 1    | 
1  | SIMPLE      | meetings_TRANSP      | ref  | meeting_uid,index1 | meeting_uid | 767     | test.meetings.uid        | 1    | 
1  | SIMPLE      | meetings_ACCO        | ref  | meeting_uid,index1 | meeting_uid | 767     | test.meetings.uid        | 1    | 
1  | SIMPLE      | meetings_BOOKEDITEMS | ref  | meeting_uid,index1 | meeting_uid | 767     | test.meetings.uid        | 1    |
```

#### Result of profiling

```
starting                      0.000092
checking permissions          0.000003
checking permissions          0.000002
checking permissions          0.000001
checking permissions          0.000001
checking permissions          0.000003
Opening tables                0.000036
System lock                   0.000008
init                          0.000033
optimizing                    0.000005
statistics                    0.000035
preparing                     0.000019
Creating tmp table            0.000165
executing                     0.000004
Copying to tmp table          1.790968
converting HEAP to MyISAM     1.669041
Copying to tmp table on disk  28.32606
Sorting result                0.141737
Sending data                  0.000099
end                           0.000005
removing tmp table            0.022097
end                           0.000014
query end                     0.000008
closing tables                0.000017
freeing items                 0.000779
logging slow query            0.000004
cleaning up                   0.000005
```

#### Part Solution

Based on Eric R. Rath's help below I have profiled the query and by adding max_heap_table_size=256M & tmp_table_size=256M to the MySQL config I have been able to eliminate the execution steps "converting HEAP to MyISAM" and "Copying to tmp table on disk".

Although this beings the total execution time down to under 2 seconds, I am still not convinced this is everything I can do so if there are any other suggestions in terms of query optimisation please let me know.

#### Profiling following max_heap_table_size & tmp_table_size config

```
...
executing                     0.000004
Copying to tmp table          1.790968
Sorting result                0.141737
...
```

Comment: `Order by` statement always slows a lot the query. Also you can remove the alias on `meeting` table since using alias forces MySQL to look trough all fields on table

Comment: Could you also paste the output of the `explain` of the query? I.e: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. This will help us understand how the query execution plan looks like and what indices are used.

Comment: Try adding an index on `(item_type, meeting_id)`

Comment: Are your tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: @ypercube it already has that as an index (I updated query so that meeting_id is now meeting_uid); InnoDB

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand done. I have also included the indexes that pertain to the query. There are also other indexes including ones for id but since they are not used in any of the joins or sort I have excluded them.

Comment: @Nico thanks for the suggestion but these queries are auto generated & I would prefer to keep consistency in convention over saving a few milliseconds.

Comment: @Precastic: `(item_type, meeting_uid)` is different than the `(meeting_uid, item_type)` you have.

Comment: And what are the `PRIMARY` keys of those two tables? Are there any `UNIQUE` indexes? We wouldn't have to ask all of these if you had included the tables' definitions. Right now, it's not obvious why (or if) you need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @ypercube I have now added this. I have created a separate database just for this test so index names have changed slightly. I am realising that I'm more of a noob than I thought!

Comment: Seeing your DDL-statements, can I ask the purpose of the varchar uid-column? Why can't you have a simple `meeting_id` column in the booked items table with a foreign key to `meetings.id`?

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand I ask myself that every time I look at it :) This is an existing client solution that I ported to MySQL, so to go & find everywhere meeting_id is used as a foreign key and replace it with id would take ages and not really be worth the time spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think index2 is unnecessary and can be removed; it's a prefix of index1.  This won't decrease the query time, though.

The EXPLAIN output shows the real culprit: "Using temporary, using filesort".  Sometimes you can avoid this by having MySQL perform ordering with the same key used to join.  If you change index1 to (meeting_id, datetime), it might be able to do so.  If you need to keep item_type in index1, you could either add it as the third column in the index, or include an IN() clause in the query with all values.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - will try them. The problem is really that datetime is not the only column that gets sorted on but is the one sorted on most often. Also, I have updated the question to include indexes from all tables for clarity.

Comment: You can use MySQL's profiling to verify the culprit.  Run `SET PROFILING=1`, then your query, then `SHOW PROFILES`, find your query, then `SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY n`.  The last command will generate a table of fine-grained steps necessary to execute your query, along with the time necessary for each step.

Comment: The result is that the Copying to tmp table on disk = 28.3 seconds... I have included the full result in the question.

Comment: Thanks for this! I added max_heap_table_size=256M & tmp_table_size=256M to the config which caused "Copying to tmp table on disk = 28.3 seconds" to be replaced by "Copying to tmp table, 2.27"; however I am still not happy that this is everything I can do (what happens when you have 10 ppl hitting it at the same time - you suck up 2.5G of RAM?). Please let me know what you think. Is there anything else I'm missing/could do? Ideally, I would like to get rid of the need for the temp table? I find it hard to believe the query takes <0.5 seconds with no sort/distinct but +2 seconds with it.

Comment: "...ORDER BY ... LIMIT N" queries often face this problem.  Your current query requires MySQL to 1) restrict the results to those rows that meet the WHERE restrictions, 2) sort all of them, and 3) return the first N results.  The trick is to modify either the query or the schema to allow using the same index for restricting and ordering.  This way, MySQL can avoid finding *all* the results that meet the restrictions before ordering *all* of them.  Instead, it keeps a much smaller set of results, and is able to update those results as it processes the rows.  It's not always easy.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check the indexes.

Do you have a composite index on meeting_id and item_type in bookeditems?

Do you have an index on meeting id on meetings, and if it is in a composite key, is it the first index?

Do you have a clustered index on datetime on meetings?

Instead of doing distinct, can you put a subquery to get the top of the stack for each meeting id?

something like:

```
select * from meetings a
where datetime = (select max(datetime) from meetings 
where meetingid = a.meetingid)
```

Instead of left joining, can you use a case statement over meeting type to get the same data?

Comment: By composite I assume you mean an index that includes both fields? Answer: yes
Yes, I have indexes on meeting id in meetings table.
I have no idea what a clustered index is or how to create one in MySQL - I will have to read up before answering taht
I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with your suggested subquery? How would that speed it up?
Yes, I could do a case statement to get bookeditem type in the meetings table if that's what you mean... that is actually what the original query does - I stripped it out to avoid complexity

Answer (score 0):

You could try to help the optimizer by first `SELECT`-ing the records that are of interests (using `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`), and then use that result to join with the other tables. Using this approach the index on `datetime` can be used fully for the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`-clauses. Here is what this approach would look like:

```
SELECT
  `meetings`.`id` AS `meeting_id`,
  `meetings`.`uid` AS meeting_uid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
   DISTINCT CASE bookeditems.item_type
     WHEN 'SER' THEN bookeditems.id
     ELSE NULL
   END
  ) AS meetings_SERV_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
   DISTINCT CASE bookeditems.item_type
     WHEN 'TRA' THEN bookeditems.id
     ELSE NULL
   END
  ) AS meetings_TRANSP_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
   DISTINCT CASE bookeditems.item_type
     WHEN 'ACC' THEN bookeditems.id
     ELSE NULL
   END
  ) AS meetings_ACCO_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(bookeditems.id) AS meetings_BOOKEDITEMS_ids
FROM (
  SELECT id
  FROM meetings
  ORDER BY `datetime`
  LIMIT 0, 50
) filtered_meetings
INNER JOIN meetings
  ON meetings.id = filtered_meetings.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bookeditems
  ON meeting_uid = bookeditems.meeting_uid
GROUP BY meeting_uid
```

Notable differences:

- We only join the booked items table once. In the select-statement we use the `GROUP_CONCAT` together with `CASE` statements to select all ids within a meeting group that match a certain criteria. Additionally, for this to work we need to add a `GROUP BY` statement to group all rows that represent the same meeting.
  This means that we will potentially get a string of ids for `meetings_SERV_ids`, `meetings_TRANSP_ids`, `meetings_ACCO_ids` and `meetings_BOOKEDITEMS_ids`. So remember to `explode`, or equivalent, in the client code handling the result rows.

Comment: This in fact takes longer to execute than the original query (sorting now 16 sec). I have updated the question with the create table definition & added why I want related tables like I do & not as you suggest a concatenated list of ID's in a single field.

Comment: I am realising that I'm more of a noob than I thought!

Comment: Sorry, that was just off of the top of my head without any test tables and data.

Comment: Also, can you post some sample (desired) output. I don't think I quite understand your desired output-format

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question... in order for you to see what my desired output-format is I would need to include the SQL statements from my solution (20-30 fields). Does it suffice to say I would like a unique list of meetings (i.e. only 1 row per meeting) with related data from bookeditems either as aggregated data - SUM(`meetings_ACCO`.`cost`) AS total_cost - or as "exists" logic - IF( `meetings_ACCO`.`id` > 0, 1, 0 ) AS acco_exists